# Export then Import a list between 2 farms, when there are users who are no longer exists inside Active directory

Tags: 2013, user-profile, administration, export, import

I have 2 sharepoint on-premises farms 2013, which are inside the same domain (are integrated with the same Active directory and users), as follow:-

1. FarmA which is an old farm, and it contain a lot of documents which were added/edited by users who left the company (users who no longer have a username inside Active directory).
2. FarmB is a newer farm. and i want to move some documents libraries from old FarmA to the newer FarmB.
3. so i will use the Export/Import approach, as it will preserve the document properties such as created,modified, created-by & modified-by ..
4. so inside FarmA i run the following script to export the document library:-

   > Export-SPWeb -Identity "http://farmA/HR/" -ItemUrl "GeneralDocuments"
   >   -Path "c:\1.cmp" -CompressionSize 1000 -IncludeVersions All -IncludeUserSecurity -Force –Verbose
5. then inside FarmB i run the following script to import the above document library:-

   > Import-SPWeb http://farmB/sites/HR/ –Path "c:\16.cmp"
   >   -NoFileCompression -IncludeUserSecurity –Verbose

now my concern was, that inside the exported document library there are many documents that have been created & modified by users who left the company, and those users can not be referenced inside the new FarmB (by reference i mean that i can not check their permission + i can not add them to a SP group + i can not add them to a People or Group site column). so i thought when i import this document library, any document which was created or modified by a user who no longer exists, will have the created-by and modified-by fields equal to the user who perform the import operation (the system account in my case),  but i was surprised that the following happened:-

1. The imported documents had the correct non-existent users assigned to the created-by and modified-by fields.
2. New user profiles for those users have been created inside the FarmB, with the correct account name and email address...

so can anyone advice how the import was more intelligent than i have expected ?? i mean how did it assign the document to non-existent users and also have created new user profiles for those non-existent users...